# FancyBox cookies resetting for pages in different subfolders

Tags: jquery, cookies, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using fancyBox2 to launch content in an iframe on page load, using an external .js call. It sets a cookie so you get the content only once, but shouldn't get it again.

Everything works great, except if you browse to a page on the site that is in a different subfolder, the cookie gets reset and Fancybox gets called again, which is not what we want.

In other words: 
example.com/subfolder1/page1.html   ---> You get Fancybox
example.com/subfolder1/page2.html
example.com/subfolder1/page3.html

example.com/subfolder2/page4.html   ----> You get Fancybox again.
example.com/subfolder2/page5.html   
example.com/subfolder2/page6.html

Does anyone know how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: Well, depends on how you are setting your cookies. If you are using the Klaus Hartl's [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for instance, then you just need to set the option `path: '/'` to make it valid through the whole site (by default the path of the cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was created.) Other plugins may give you a similar functionality